# error when trying to bind scraped news articles from RSS feed in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rss

I just ran into a recent problem with my code that might be due to an update to R or one of my R packages.

What I need to do is to scrape news articles from an RSS feed from google alerts. All was going well until recently. I am using the following code-

```
load.lib <- c("rvest", "XML", "purrr", "dplyr", "stringr", "feedeR")
install.lib<-load.lib[!load.lib %in% installed.packages()]
for(lib in install.lib) install.packages(lib,dependencies=TRUE)
sapply(load.lib,library,character=TRUE)

feed<- feed.extract("https://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/01499783252492076179/351667870973011596")
feed <- as.data.frame (feed) 
links <- feed$items.link
link <- gsub("&ct=ga&cd=.*", "", links)
link2 <- gsub("*.rct=j&sa=t&url=", "", link)
link3 <- gsub ("https://www.google.com/url", "", link2)

scrape <- function (x) {
example = read_html(x)

p_text <- example %>%
        html_nodes("p") %>%
        html_text()
}

y <- lapply (link3, scrape)

df <- do.call(rbind, y) %>%
    as.data.frame ()
```

My code breaks down at the last point-

```
df <- do.call(rbind, y) %>%
    as.data.frame ()
```

What I had before was a data frame where each row was a scraped article where columns were associated with the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, paragraph and so forth.

Now I just get this error-

```
Warning message:
In (function (..., deparse.level = 1)  :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

I am fairly certain that this has to do with the scraped articles having differing numbers of paragraphs.

Comment: I see this question is related to your new question. What is the expected output here? 20 rows with text one for each link in `link3` ? Or do you want to different row for each paragraph?

Comment: @RonakShah you are absolutely right. The two questions are linked. The end goal is to scrape a set of websites pulled from multiple RSS feeds. Then put these all in a single spreadsheet. I appreciate the help btw.

Comment: Is my answer something that you were looking for? BTW in my `data.frame` call I used `head` to select only first few links. You may want to remove to get data for all the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the text using `paste0` from each link into one string.

```
library(rvest)

scrape <- function (x) {
  example = read_html(x)
  example %>%
    html_nodes("p") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    paste0(collapse = ' ')
}


df <- data.frame(link = head(link3),
                 text = sapply(head(link3), scrape))
```

Comment: This works very well, my only addition was adding the following line "subset(, nchar(as.character()) <= 100)" The goal is to filter out paragraphs of length less than 100 characters but there was only an error returned.